# Filter data on a given date/time based on latest transaction

Tags: sql, oracle

This is an example of unitlog table content. It shows what transactions were performed and on which units and on which time/date. Units once transferred to WH can be returned back by the WH staff due to any reason. So one unit can enter/exit in WH multiple times a day. Whenever a unit has enters/accepted by warehouse this will be "WI" transaction type and before this there will always be a transaction "VT" which tells the unit to go to warehouse now.

Transaction types are:

VT : Instructed to go to warehouse W01
WI : Unit is accepted and has entered warehouse W01
V1 : Unit entering from one location to another location or you can say from one shelf to another shelf or from one conveyer to another conveyer. (doesnt matter if WH_LOC is not RTI, CONV, CONVS)
V2 : Movement within warehouse (doesnt matter)
SP : Moved the unit outside of warehouse.

Unit Status types:

FL : Unit is not wrapped and is not in the warehouse.
WH : Unit is now wrapped and can go to WH. Or is already in WH only if the WH_loc is not (RTI, CONV, CONVS,RHS)

Requirement : I need to see how many units went to the warehouse W01 on the given date and were never returned back, so it means that those units must still be in the WH or further shipped.

Approach : I was thinking to put a check mark on the last transaction of unit, that if the last transaction is SP then the unit is outside, or if the wh_loc in the last transaction is something within (RTI, CONV, CONVS,RHS) then the unit is outside. But I've no idea how to achieve this.

[image]

My Output table, if i take the report for all the units which went in warehouse should look like

[image]

Sample data is,

```
CREATE TABLE LOG( UNIT_ID INT, DATE_TRANSAC datetime, TYPE_TRANSAC varchar(10), UNIT_STAT varchar(10), WH_CODE varchar(10), WH_LOC varchar(10) );

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1129463816', '20191117 14:30:08', 'V2', 'WH', 'W01', 'I002');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200552', '20191117 15:29:50', 'WI' ,'WH', 'W01' ,'H001');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200552', '20191117 14:49:29', 'VT' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'CONV');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200552', '20191117 14:45:40', 'SP' ,'WH' ,'F01R' ,'*');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200552', '20191117 14:39:33', 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'H001');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200456', '20191117 15:30:04', 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'H001');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200346', '20191117 14:53:25', 'VI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'CONV');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200345', '20191117 15:29:21', 'SP' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'RTI');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200344', '20191117 15:35:53', 'SP' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'RTI');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200333', '20191117 14:23:06', 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'F004');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200332', '20191118 14:23:06', 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'F004');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1129463816', '20191118 16:30:29', 'SP' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'RTI');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200345', '20191118 16:35:29', 'VT' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'CONV');

insert into LOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC) values ('1193200345', '20191118 16:36:34', 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'D004');

SELECT * FROM LOG WHERE DATE_TRANSAC BETWEEN '20191117 13:00:00' and '20191117 17:00:00'
```

Oracle commands (But not showing time stamps, shows date only)

```sql
CREATE TABLE UNITLOG(

UNIT_ID NUMBER,

DATE_TRANSAC DATE,

TYPE_TRANSAC varchar2(10),

UNIT_STAT varchar2(10),

WH_CODE varchar2(10),

WH_LOC varchar2(10)

);

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1129463816',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 14:30:08', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'V2', 'WH', 'W01', 'I002');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200552',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 15:29:50', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'WI' ,'WH', 'W01' ,'H001');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200552',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 14:49:29', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'VT' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'CONV');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200552',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 14:45:40', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'SP' ,'WH' ,'F01R' ,'*');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200552',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 14:39:33', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'H001');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200456',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 15:30:04', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'H001');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200346',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 14:53:25', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'VI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'CONV');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200345',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 15:29:21', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'SP' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'RTI');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200344',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 15:35:53', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'SP' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'RTI');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200333',TO_DATE('17/10/2019 14:23:06', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'F004');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200332',TO_DATE('18/10/2019 14:23:06', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'F004');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1129463816',TO_DATE('18/10/2019 16:30:29', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'SP' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'RTI');

insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200345',TO_DATE('18/10/2019 16:35:29', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'VT' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'CONV');


insert into UNITLOG (UNIT_ID, DATE_TRANSAC, TYPE_TRANSAC, UNIT_STAT, WH_CODE, WH_LOC)

values ('1193200345',TO_DATE('18/10/2019 16:35:29', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') , 'WI' ,'WH' ,'W01' ,'D004');
```

This is the Output of sample data, I highlighted same units with same color code.

[image: This is the Output of sample data, I highlighted same units with same color code.]

And These are the outputs i require.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is for Oracle? Oracle does not have a `datetime` data type; it has `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` and both of those have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components.

Comment: @GMB i tried to if for oracle also in Live SQL online but after all insert statements when i checked select *, it showed me date only, not the time. I will put the oracle code there also

Comment: If a select after the inserts shows only date it indicates your NLS_DATE_FORMAT is set to show only date. Run "alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'" and rerun the select - you will see date and time. You can also run "select  dump(date_transac) ..." You will see the internal structure that includes the time. BTW, which set on inserts did you run - date specification totally different? ON the expected output two of the expected lines of output (ending in 423 and 457) do not exist in the input. And the other 2 don't make any since.

Comment: (cont):  You say the goal is identify "units went to the warehouse" but item ending in 816 shows only movement in the warehouse (V2). Does that imply it went into the warehouse that same day? The chronology for item 552 makes no since. Sequence: Accepted, Sent Out, Sent To, Accepted (WI,SP,VT,WI). Please clarify and give expected results for supplied test data. And finally there is no check mark on the database. Is that generated from it (by time) or is it to be user supplied?

Comment: @Belayer i Just edited and enter some more information in the question through screen shots.

Comment: @Belayer The chronology for item 552 is (WI,SP,VT,WI) it was already inside warehouse, then sent out, then sent to warehouse, then entered the warehouse. V1 is unit movement inside warehouse location and V2 is outside warehouse loacation. E.G. warehouse has many location codes inside as you can see H001, D004 and so on. So if there is V2 and WH-LOC is not something RTI CONV CONVS then it means only the unit location within the WH is getting changed. Hope my screen shots will help to clarify more

Comment: @Belayer For a unit to be inside the WH_LOC should never be RTI CONV CONVS. If transaction is V2 with WH_LOC CONV then it means unit just moved from some location to some location but is not in the warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, You need to use `analytical function` as following:

```
Select * from
(Select t.*,
       Row_number() over (partition by unit_id, trunc(DATE_TRANSAC) order by DATE_TRANSAC desc) as rn
  From UNITLOG t
Where WH_CODE = 'W01' )
Where rn = 1
  And (TYPE_TRANSAC <> 'SP' 
        or coalesce(wh_loc,'RTI') not in ('RTI', 'CONV', 'CONVS','RHS')
      );
```

`Coalesce` is used in case if it is null then it must not be included in the final output. If this is not nullable column then you can remove `coalesce`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Can you have a look again. I updated my desired output as per the sample data.